# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer python for loop

Tags: python, loops, datetime, for-loop

I am trying to create a function that returns data starting from a given year and given month to today's year and month. For simplicity I have replaced what I want my function to do with print statements of outer loop and inner loop. I am getting error TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

**Defining function**

```
def frequency_database(df,start_month,start_year):
    data = pd.DataFrame([])
    import datetime
    start_month=int(start_month)
    start_year=int(start_year)
    today = datetime.date.today()
    today_year=today.strftime('%Y')

    for y in range(start_year,today_year):
        print('Outer loop enter for year', y)
        Some function here which I want to do.............
        for x in range(start_month,13):
            print('Inner loop enter for month number',x)
            Some function here which I want to do.............
```

**Calling funtion**

```
frequency_database(df,1,2015)
```

**Error**

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

**Stack Trace as requested**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-06567ae5d027> in <module>
     12             print('Inner loop enter for month number',x)
     13 
---> 14 frequency_database(df,1,2015)

<ipython-input-37-06567ae5d027> in frequency_database(df, start_month, start_year)
      7     today_year=today.strftime('%Y')
      8 
----> 9     for y in range(start_year,today_year):
     10         print('Outer loop enter for year', y)
     11         for x in range(start_month,13):

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Replace `today_year=today.strftime('%Y')` with `today_year=int(today.strftime('%Y'))`

Comment: Please include the stack trace of your exception and tell us which line it is indicating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you tried to give `range` a `str` which is `today_year=today.strftime('%Y')`.

Just replace the line

```
today_year=today.strftime('%Y')
```

with

```
today_year=int(today.strftime('%Y'))
```

As pointed out by [Stargazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2904202/stargazer), you could do,

```
today_year = today.year
```

instead of converting the `str` to `int`

Comment: No need to that. Just `today.year` will return the year as an int

Comment: Sure. I will update the answer with that. Thank you